# How to add custom font to UILabel but have label retain its size from storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I currently am subclassing a UILabel to change the font to a custom font, however I would also like it to retain the size that I have set in storyboard for each label. Is there a method of doing this and also detect the current chosen style bold etc and replacing it with the relevant custom font if possible?

Here is the code I use to set the current font.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
 self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
 if (self) {
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerLT-Roman" size:17.0];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a custom font, to your app, check the following link: http://shang-liang.com/blog/custom-fonts-in-ios4/

Now, to keep the size set in the storyboard, it should be fine:

```
self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerLT-Roman" size:self.font.pointSize];
```

Comment: Thanks that works great for the font size but what about the style of the font?

Comment: I checked out your link I already has custom fonts setup but +1 for the help thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I wrote my own solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281017/1565615 @Nathan R. helped me with getting the font size.

Then I extracted the font-weight component of the UIFont description and changed the font accordingly this is great with custom font's as now I can set the font size and style in storyboard and it will set that within the subclassed version of the UILabel.

I wish there was an easier way to identify the type of font-weight being used like font.fontWeight I realise that my solution is longwinded but it works any further ideas would be useful.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
  if (self)
  {
    NSString *fontInfo = self.font.description;//Complete font description
    NSArray *splitUpFontDescription = [fontInfo componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];//Split up
    NSString *fontWeight = [[NSString alloc]init];
    for (NSString *tempString in splitUpFontDescription)
    {
      if ([tempString rangeOfString:@"font-weight"].location != NSNotFound)//Font weight found
      {
        fontWeight = [tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                  withString:@""];//Remove whitespace
        fontWeight = [fontWeight stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"font-weight:"
                                                           withString:@""];
      }
    }
    NSLog(@"Font style (Weight) = *%@*",fontWeight);
    if ([fontWeight isEqualToString:@"normal"])
    {
      //Set to custom font normal.
      self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerLT-Roman" size:self.font.pointSize];
    }
    else if([fontWeight isEqualToString:@"bold"])
    {
      //Set to custom font bold.
      self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerLT-Bold" size:self.font.pointSize];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
```